# How to draw line of ten thousands of points with WPF within 0.5 second?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, templates, itemscontrol

I am writing [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) code to show a real-time plot which is a connected line containing about
10,000 points. It takes about 5 seconds to show a picture in my computer. Does anyone have an idea to make it quicker and within 0.5 second?

```
class eee : FrameworkElement
{

    public eee()
    {
        _children = new VisualCollection(this);
        Random rand = new Random();
        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext dx = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            Pen drawingPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
            double x=rand.Next(300);
            double y = rand.Next(300);
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 0.1)
            {
                y = 100 + rand.Next(100);
                dx.DrawLine(drawingPen, new Point(i, x), new Point(i + 1, y));
                x = y;
            }
        }
         _children.Add(dv);
    }
```

Comment: Charles's is just the points, if you need the lines, use the same method, it will work fine.  YOu have to leverage the retained graphics system.

Answer (score 38):

[Charles Petzold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx) does exactly that. It is even faster on my host (< 0.3 secs), and the point's are even DataBound!! ;)

[Tamir Khason](http://khason.net/blog/how-to-high-performance-graphics-in-wpf/) does this also, with lines and goes into more depth about Bitmap style performance WPF [here](http://khason.net/blog/performance-appliance-of-rendertargetbitmap/).

[Rico Mariani](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2006/08/31/733887.aspx) has some guidance for 3D high performance graphics, essentially leveraging value types can improve your throughput if well thought out.

[Jianzhong Zhang](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFChart3D.aspx) gives my new favourate tutorials on this subject, 3D scatter plot several tens of thousands of data points animated and interactive.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the code sample is 1) a test to try a something that isn't really the sample or 2) a homework.

Try to override the OnRender and do something like:

```
Pen drawingPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    dc.DrawRectangle(Background, null, new Rect(RenderSize));


            double x=rand.Next(300);
            double y = rand.Next(300);
            for (double i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 0.1)
            {
                y = 100 + rand.Next(100);
                dc.DrawLine(drawingPen, new Point(i, x), new Point(i + 1, y));
                x = y;
            }


}
```

or for something with real data, consider if you really need to show every point depending on the resolution of the visual context. ( If your scale is 0-10 and you are producing points 0.0001,0.00015 are they really gone differ on your scale)

Comment: The DrawRectangle may not be necessary as the contents were (in my case) cleared on each render.

Answer (score 1):

Should the lines be selectable? You can draw lines in the image, then give it as a source to Image control. It will draw faster but you will lose ability to interact with lines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)? Using a graphics card will speed up things.

Comment: WPF uses hardware acceleration too.

Answer (score 0):

[Monogame](http://www.monogame.net/), based on XNA, is alive. You can use its power to solve some special tasks requiring huge graphics performance and even inject its windows in WPF GUI.