# WPF canvas performance- children.add called many times

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I'm drawing a lot of lines on a long canvas (think stripchart) and have it tuned fairly well for performance, using the low-level geometry classes and freezing them, etc. This improved performance dramatically, but it still takes a few seconds to load a few thousand items into the canvas. I ran a performance analysis on the application, and it looks like a big percentage of the time is taken by each call to `canvas.children.add()`. I've read that this should be a lightweight call, and since I'm calling it numerous times in one method, it shouldn't be trying to do anything heavy inbetween... Could there possibly be any other reason this might be taking so much time? And any way I might speed it up?

The performance is not terrible, but I fear it could become more of a problem later when I need to deal with larger sets of data.

Just for reference, it looks like it is called 1400 times in this sample, and it taking almost 3 seconds of CPU time on a modern/fast laptop.

The canvas is contained in a hierachy of other controls though, so I'm curious if they might be contributing to this.

Extra note: I'm also not setting a specific height on the canvas, as it is set to fill the grid parent container. Could this be a source of the problems?

Comment: As far as performance is concerned, You could try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx Stream Geometry which is most light weight construct than Drawing Context.

Comment: yep, already using the stream geometry, and with good results. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Main problem is that Children.Add is always a slow operation, even if you use StreamGeometry objects. I faced the same problem recently and concluded the following:
If you put a bunch of objects into a new canvas and nest it into the main canvas, the performance of the addition operation will be increased dramatically.
So, instead of adding 1400 elements, put 200 elements in 7 canvases and add those 7 canvases to the main canvas.
Since all objects now belong to different canvases, you will need to adjust your app a bit, but this would be a less drastical solution than moving to an alternative solution like DrawingVisual

Comment: Jaime, how big of perfromance gain would you estimate from this? ie 10% or 100% speed gain? Thanks.

Comment: In my specific case (300 objects added at one time over a 5000+ children collection), I had a delay of 2.5 seconds and became 0.3 seconds.

Comment: i found out i was actually using pathgeometry instead of stream, so just finished converting - it's definitely faster now, but still probably over a second. So now splitting up canvases will be the next thing I try when time permits.

Comment: I'm curious though if you tried putting the multiple canvases into a stackpanel instead of a parent canvas? would  make it easier to figure out positioning etc, but mostly curious if that would help or hurt performance.

Comment: I have not tried with stackpanel. it doesn't make sense to me because, child-canvases will be placed in different positions. With a parent canvas, all child canvases can be overlaid one on each other, so objects inside will have a common coordinate system.

Comment: right. Yes, in my specific case the child canvases can all be sequential with each other, so I could potentially use a stackpanel. would help with not having to do the positioning, but not sure if it would hurt or help performace over using a parent canvas.

Comment: How does nesting in another Canvas give better performance? You'd still need to call Canvas.Children.Add(), right? I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @Wout, Sorry for answering tooooo late. Yes, you are missing something. A canvas with 10 nested canvas of 1,000 objects performs better than a single canvas with 10,000 objects. The insertion of new objects is faster. I have tried this intensively.

Comment: Probably the Canvas recalculates something after adding every new element. The recalculation is dependent on all the elements already present in collection. This would imply quadratic time complexity or more precisely T1 ~ 0.5 * N * (N-1) ~ 0.5 * N^2. If you use M canvases, time complexity should be T2 = M * 0.5 * (N / M)^2 = 0.5 / M * N^2 = T1/M. This could be resolved by changing architecture of Canvas for example by adding methods BeginUpdate / EndUpdate like in Delphi language VCL library.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add about the hierarchy of controls the canvas is within, and the height of the canvas:

the Canvas always takes as much space as its given, and no matter what children u add to it - it NEVER triggers a new Measuer/Arrange passes on its parents. therefor whatever u do inside a canvas could never affect the visual tree it is contained in.
To sum it up - the problem cannot come from there, and the suggestion about the StreamGeomatry is exactly right- this is what causing u the performance issues, and switching to streamgeormatry would solve it.

Comment: I'm already using streamgeometry for all the applicable added children. they did help performance a lot, but still looking to improve substantially.

Comment: made a liar out of me- i'd actually wound up using pathgeometry at some point. Just converted to streamgeo and is definitely faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you draw your shapes directly into an image instead of adding them as children. 
Rendering children has a HUGE overhead (as you can see).

There's a similar question with a reference to some helpful articles:

[How to draw line of ten thousands of points with WPF within 0.5 second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150060/how-to-draw-line-of-ten-thousands-of-points-with-wpf-within-0-5-second)

Comment: Was hoping to avoid this, since I have other things going on which may make it complicated to always redraw. such as, text boxes and images added on top which are draggable, and the section is very long so exists in a scrollable container. Lots of variables to consider...

Comment: Depending on how critical performance is for you, you might want to consider a solution in one of the many gaming frameworks in C# (i.e. something that manipulates sprites). Of course - if you also want to use other UI Framework mechanism that won't really help you...
BTW: Under certain conditions WPF will not use hardware rendering, which can dramatically reduce performance - you can check it with this method 'Debug.WriteLine("WPF RenderCapabilities: Rendering Tier  = " + (RenderCapability.Tier >> 16) + " (Desired 2, 0 Means no Hardware Acceleration)");'