# How to draw FrameworkElement on drawingContext?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frameworkelement

I have a refrence to a `FrameworkElement` named _frameworkElement 
I need to draw a `FrameworkElement` on a drawingContext at the `OnRender` event.

Like this:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
   drawingContext. ??
   base.OnRender(drawingContext);
}
```

What I need is to consider any render transform applied to the _frameworkElement

Any clean solution for this problem ?
Thanks

**EDIT**

*Why would I need to override OnRender:*

As I have a graphical application, user can draw shapes, and select multiple shapes using a selection tool that would draw rectangle selection area.

What I do is I re-parent selected shapes from stage Canvas to a selection Canvas which user can move and resize, after transformation on selection Canvas, user will click on stage Canvas, then I re-parent shapes to the stage Canvas.

*The problem:*

There is a bottleneck when removing children from Canvas to Canvas, Children.Remove & Children.Add will cost time to implement, specially when user selects large number of shapes to transform.

So ?

I thought not to re-parent selected shapes, instead draw them on the drawingContext of the selection Canvas by overriding OnRender

Comment: Why would you do that? I cannot think of a situation where you need to override OnRender() in WPF. Please give some more details as to what your're trying to do.

Comment: There are situations where that override is necessary. I have used it to draw live data representations (imagine if you will, a heart EKG of sorts) that responds to mouse positioning and events. This is a valid scenario.

However, it would be helpful to know what you need to accomplish if we are to help you get there. :)

Comment: Please see EDIT above to explain why I needed to override OnRender()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't believe you can do that nor does it really make sense. The `DrawingContext` is unique to each `UIElement` and the framework handles calling the appropriate drawing methods as they're being enumerated (e.g. each element has it's own OnRender pass).

I'm not entirely following your design + problem, but maybe these will help?

[WPF canvas performance- children.add called many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846502/wpf-canvas-performance-children-add-called-many-times)

[How to draw line of ten thousands of points with WPF within 0.5 second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150060/how-to-draw-line-of-ten-thousands-of-points-with-wpf-within-0-5-second?lq=1)

If you need to deep-dive into how WPF renders, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good read.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Code:

```
private FrameworkElement _frameworkElement = null;

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    var rect = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Size(Width, Height));

    dc.DrawImage(UtilityWPF.RenderControl(_frameworkElement, Width.ToInt_Round(), Height.ToInt_Round(), false), rect);
}
```

Helper Method:

```
public const double DPI = 96;

/// <summary>
/// This tells a visual to render itself to a wpf bitmap
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This fixes an issue where the rendered image is blank:
/// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/07/03/rendertargetbitmap-tips.aspx
/// </remarks>
public static BitmapSource RenderControl(FrameworkElement visual, int width, int height, bool isInVisualTree)
{
    if (!isInVisualTree)
    {
        // If the visual isn't part of the visual tree, then it needs to be forced to finish its layout
        visual.Width = width;
        visual.Height = height;
        visual.Measure(new Size(width, height));        //  I thought these two statements would be expensive, but profiling shows it's mostly all on Render
        visual.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
    }

    RenderTargetBitmap retVal = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, DPI, DPI, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
    {
        VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(visual);
        ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(width, height)));
    }

    retVal.Render(dv);      //  profiling shows this is the biggest hit

    return retVal;
}
```